# Main class gets terminated when calling a loginform class

Tags: java, swing

I want to create an application in a swing to which validation of user is performed by providing login form.
My application program name is application.java
 I developed a Login form(Loginform.java) using swings . It worked successfully .
when i access it using my application.java class It performs validation and then complete application is terminate.
please give me suggestion by which validation is done and My application program not to be teminated.

Comment: Please, add snippets of your code to direct us. What form do you use to implement `Loginform.java` `JFrame` or `Dialog`?

Comment: I use JFrame for developing LoginForm.java

Answer (score 3):

I suppose if you use `Loginform.java` as JFrame, bear in mind that on close `login` you kill all your program. Implement `Login` form as Dialog and all will work as you expected.

Just initiate your main frame `application.java` (set class name with uppercase), Show Login `JDialog` Box and on success set main JFrame visible.

`JDialog` examples: [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1220__JDialog.htm)

How to create Login Dialog box [see here](http://www.zentut.com/java-swing/simple-login-dialog/)

[image]

Comment: please give me the link or a tutorial.

Comment: "*bear in mind that on close `login` you kill all your program."*  Not necessarily, see David's answer.  OTOH +1 for the mention of dialogs & links to a page with examples of using modal dialogs.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely due to the fact in your *LoginForm.java* you have called `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` which will cause your [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and [Initial thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) to be killed.

Rather use something like:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

On a side note, it is not considered good practice to use multiple `JFrame`s:

- [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

You can have a look at the [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) which will allow you to flip between `JPanel`s on a single `JFrame`. Or use a `JDialog` as your login screen which will initiate the main `JFrame`